# MYSQL LIMIT only the values where "viewed"=1 , but not viewed="0"

Tags: mysql, where-clause, limit

This is a tough one for me. I have a table that holds user notifications. There is a column "VIEWED" where 0 means it has NOT been viewed, 1 means it has.

I want to generate my list of notifications, SELECT * that is unviewed (0), however in the case that I have no un viewed notification, I don't want to just display "no notififications" I want to display a few old ones.

I'm already showing my most recent unviewed first. Is there a way to do something that shows ALL unviewed, but only a few viewed? Like below?

```
  $QUERY= "SELECT * FROM point_member_notifications WHERE account_id='$accountid' ORDER BY viewed ASC, created_date DESC (LIMIT 10 WHERE VIEWED='1') "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want `UNION ALL`, to limit the '`VIEWED'` old ones, just place the `limit` clause inside the parentheses that enclose the `SELECT`

```
(SELECT * FROM point_member_notifications WHERE account_id='$accountid' ORDER BY viewed ASC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM point_member_notifications WHERE account_id='$accountid' WHERE VIEWED='1' created_date DESC LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: You're right.. and you answered first. It's actually quite a simple solution too lol.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of LIMIT and UNION (or UNION ALL if you don't want to remove duplicate records). That could look like:

```
(SELECT * 
FROM point_member_notifications WHERE account_id='$accountid' AND VIEWED='1'
ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM point_member_notifications WHERE account_id='$accountid'  AND VIEWED='0' 
ORDER BY created_date DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

If you want to have 10 records unviewed + the 10 old records you need to put the 2nd SELECT in brackets too, otherwise the LIMIT 10 at the end will limit the whole thing. An ORDER BY viewed should not be necessary since UNION already selects the unviewed first and then the others.